# Moving Person Accounts Layouts and Workflows

Tags: person-accounts

Has anyone had any success using Packages and ANT to deploy Person Account Layouts and workflows from a Sandbox to Production?

I can't find any information on this in implementation guide or the Metadata components in Eclipse.

The Implementation guide I was reading is available [here](https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_B2C_implementation_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mike you will find meta-data files for person account in Eclipse Force.com IDE & use these files for deployment in production or any other sandbox as describe below navigation.
Navigate to your Force.com IDE project as shown below:

**Workflow Rules:** ProjectName | src | workflows | Account.workflow
**Object:**  ProjectName | src | objects | PersonAccount.object
**Layouts:**  ProjectName | src | layouts | PersonAccount_XXXXX___Layout.layout

`

> Note: Make sure you have synced objects/layouts/workflows in your force.com IDE project

Comment: I was able to get the layouts, thanks for that!  But I can't find the PersonAccount object